# Using FTP client to send file to FTP server

Tags: c, ftp

I would like to create a C program to send a .xml file to a FTP server which I have been given the username and password to periodically. What would be the easiest way to do this?

One idea I had was to just create strings containing the instructions and execute these using `system("command")` however I have not used FTP before so do not know the correct commands to do so. Is there a better way to go about this? Or if this way is valid what commands would i use to send the file via FTP.

Comment: It depends a *lot* on the FTP program on your system. It might have options to be able to send a file using only command-line options, or it might not. You really need to research this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ftp -u ftp://user:passt@ftp.ftpserver.com/local-file.txt local-file.txt
```

Probably lftp is a better choice [here](https://docs.salixos.org/wiki/How_to_send/get_a_file_to/from_a_remote_server_via_command_line_or_script).

```
lftp ftp://user:password@host  -e "put local-file.name; bye"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried the lftp command however the response i get is "put: XMLTest-Automated.xml: Fatal error: Certificate verification: Not trusted"

Comment: Corrected it, involved adding "set ftp:ssl-allow false" to lftp.config

Answer (score -1):

Rather than a C program, a shell script would be more easier for you to manage and get things done in this case.

Or you can use 'scp' to send file this

```
$ scp <username>@<ftp-server-ipaddress>:/path/ftp-server/dir <your file>
```

Or 'sftp', this has an added advantage to surf the ftp server

```
 $ sftp username@<ftp-server-ipaddress>
password:
$ ls
$ pwd
```

You can use simple linux commands and use the ftp server, incase you need to check your host commands you have to add 'l' as prefix

```
$lls
$lpwd                   # working on your machine with sftp login

$ put <your .xml file>  # puts your file to ftpserver
$ get <anyfile>         # gets files from ftp server
```